# What word would you use to describe a situation where words are not necessary?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Example: "Their love was so strong that it was unspoken. Words were (replace) 'not necessary' for them to display their affection towards one another.

Answer (score 3):

May be not the exact answer, however I think it could convey the message in the best way.

> **Words are unable to express** their love.

Answer (score 2):

They shared a **tacit** understanding.  Words were **gratuitous**.

> [tacit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tacit)
> : expressed or understood without being directly stated
> Synonyms
>     implied, implicit, unexpressed, unspoken, unvoiced, wordless
> Antonyms
>     explicit, express, expressed, spoken, stated, voiced

...

> [gratuitous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gratuitous)
> : not necessary or appropriate
> Antonyms
>     essential, indispensable, necessary, needed, needful, required
> *(Synonyms omitted -- none of the ones provided come close enough)*

(From Merriam-Webster online)

Answer (score 1):

> Words were ________ (meaning *not necessary*).  (idea: for them to
>   display their affection towards one another)

Words were *superfluous*.

meaning "unnecessary or needless" -- Random House.

Answer (score 0):

you may say that their love was **indescribable** or **beyond description**

- *Indescribable* means impossible to ​describe, because too intense, extreme, etc, for words.

you may also speak of an *overwhelming* love.

- *Overwhelming* means very great in number, effect, or force, i.e. extreme. it is used to describe something that is so confusing, difficult, etc., that you feel unable to deal with it.